# Export to pipe delimited .txt file without quotes

Tags: vba, excel, export, delimiter

I've created a VBA code that exports data to export.txt file from a single, hardcoded worksheet. I had to use two For loops because I didn't know in what different (and easy) way I would skip the two lines consisting of unnecessary information from the export perspective (file type and primary key for another macro). Nevertheless, the macro does its job...

```
Sub VBA_Write_to_a_text_file()
Dim filename As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

filename = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "/export.txt"
Open filename For Output As #1

Set rng = Sheets(22).Range("A1:G1")
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            Write #1, cellValue
        Else
            Write #1, cellValue,
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Set rng = Sheets(22).Range("A4:G18")
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            Write #1, cellValue
        Else
            Write #1, cellValue,
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Close #1
End Sub
```

... with the exception for two issues:

1. Pipe delimiter issue: I cannot change comma "," delimiter for pipe "|" with changing the syntax below. This syntax is probably reserved to comma-separated files only. What would you recommend?

   ```
   If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
   Write #1, cellValue Else
   Write #1, cellValue,
   ```
2. Unnecessary quotes: In the same bit provided above I use Write instead of Print. I know that Print will get rid of quotes, but it will also remove delimiters producing a tab-delimited file which is not an option. And the pipes issue is of higher priority than the quotes one, but ideally I am aiming at fixing both.

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions.

exemplary source data:
[image: example source data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally agree with Dave's suggestion to use `FileSystemObject` - it is available in the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library which you should add into your project. The other suggestion I have is to iterate the rows of your data and create an array for each row. You can then use the `Join` function to convert that array into a string with each value delimited with your choice of delimiter e.g. `|`.

Turing a row of a `Range` into a 1 dimensional array needs a little trick with the `Transpose` function. It does save you from having to always check for the last field and not output a delimiter on that iteration. It also saves you having to use a nested loop.

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export()

    'for file system
    Dim objFs As New FileSystemObject
    Dim tsOut As TextStream

    'for data
    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim varRowData As Variant
    Dim strRowData As String
    Dim strDelimiter As String

    'counters
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    'set up data
    Set rngHeaders = Sheet2.Range("A1:F1")
    Set rngData = Sheet2.Range("A3:F10")

    'set delimiter
    strDelimiter = "|"

    'set up file system
    Set tsOut = objFs.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\out.txt", True)

    'output header
    varRowData = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngHeaders.Value))
    strRowData = VBA.Join(varRowData, strDelimiter)
    tsOut.WriteLine strRowData

    'output data
    For lngCounter = 1 To rngData.Rows.Count
        Set rngRow = rngData.Rows(lngCounter)
        varRowData = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngRow.Value))
        strRowData = VBA.Join(varRowData, strDelimiter)
        tsOut.WriteLine strRowData
    Next lngCounter

    'clean up
    tsOut.Close
    Set tsOut = Nothing
    Set objFs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a ready-to-use solution that you've given me. It's brilliant. I forgot to mention a few requirements. So far I haven't managed to solve the last one: 
1. the generated file name must be predefined and best in the same folder as the source spreadsheet; `Set tsOut = objFs.CreateTextFile(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "/export.txt", True)`
2. Delimiter must be present at the very beginning and end of the line: `strRowData = "|" & VBA.Join(varRowData, strDelimiter) & "|"`
**3. My open question: rngData parameter should use some loop to account for new lines**

Comment: I also managed the 3rd problem with the following, quite simple syntax I found on the web: 
`'for data
    Dim last As Double
    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim varRowData As Variant
    Dim strRowData As String
    Dim strDelimiter As String

    'counters
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    'set up data
    With Sheet13
        last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Set rngHeaders = Sheet13.Range("A1:G1")
    Set rngData = Sheet13.Range("A4:G" & last)`

Comment: Good work - you could also use something like this: `Set rngData = Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Range("A3"), Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row, Sheet2.Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Column))`

Answer (score 1):

Use a FileSystemObject to create your text file and write whatever you please to it:

```
Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile : Set oFile = oFso.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\myfile.txt")
```

Then you can write anything you want with the following commands:

```
oFile.WriteLine "This will write a line and end it with a vbNewLine"
oFile.Write "Where this write method will "
oFile.Write "just write to the file without the new line on the end of the text."
oFile.WriteLine "You|can|send|pipe|delimited|text|or|whatever|else|you|like"
oFile.Close 'close and save the updated text file
```

You can control whether or not you send quotes by doubling up as required, for example:

```
oFile.WriteLine """This is quoted text"""
```

Will print "This is quoted text" in your file.

Comment: Thanks @Dave for your suggestion! Great tip. Does wonders and I haven't came across it even though I have searched quite a few websites.